# Getting viper-mode to play well with magit-key-mode

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, magit

I use viper-mode in emacs and magit with magit-key-mode. Problem I am having is that I don't want viper to load in magit-key-mode as I then must hit Ctl-z to get into emacs mode before selecting a key in the magit-key-mode buffer? Any ideas on how to selectively turn off viper-mode for magit-key-mode?

Answer (score 1):

```
;; don't allow viper-mode to load in certain modes
(when (boundp 'viper-emacs-state-mode-list)
  (mapc (lambda (mode)
          (add-to-list 'viper-emacs-state-mode-list mode))
        '(magit-key-mode)))
```